# How to fix Name Expected error when building an Angular 7 library?

Tags: angular, webpack, uglifyjs, angular-library

I am trying to build an Angular 7 library and when it reaches the **Minifying UMD bundle** it crashes with this error:

I launch the build with this command: **ng build dual-range-calendar**

```
BUILD ERROR
Name expected
SyntaxError: Name expected
    at JS_Parse_Error.get (eval at <anonymous> 
(C:\Users\daniel.mancera\Documents\dev\core\node_modules\uglify- 
js\tools\node.js:20:1), <anonymous>:71:23)
```

I expect to transpile into a dist folder correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well!

I solved it.

I had an import ending with an slash:

**import { NgbDate, NgbDatepicker, NgbCalendar } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/';**

It made the UMD bundle to crash.

If you have similar problems check all your imports.